# How does one split a set of files across a set of DVDs?

Tags: windows, backup, dvd, dvd-burning

I have a set of files which total about 12 GB, which I would like to burn to a few DVDs. I could manually try to "bucket" things, but it would be nice if there was a piece of software which could put enough files on the first DVD until it runs out, then puts more on another DVD, etc.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Size Me](http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2)

> SizeMe makes it possible to scan a directory and compare it to how many floppy/zip/CD-R/DVD-discs you need. (Many calls it spanning or span of elements over a medium). It tries to fill each disc up as much as possible, and gives you the result on each disc

Donationware

Comment: This answer could do with a few more details (links can go stale eventually)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use an archiver, here's a list of programs that will do what you want.  I haven't used any of these except Burn to the Brim, and that was several versions and years ago.

- [Burn to the Brim](http://bttb.sourceforge.net/) - Open Source
- [DiscFit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/discfit/) - Open Source
- [DVD Span](http://hcidesign.com/dvdspan/) - Shareware
- [File Sift](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filesift/) - Open Source
- [FillCD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Rip-Other-Tools/FillCD.shtml) - Abandonware
- [Ignition](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/index.php?ignition) - Freeware
- [SizeMe](http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2) - Freeware